# How to create a function to delete everything of a table? Vue.js - Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to be able to click on a button and delete everything from a table, this is what I have now. I'm using the `laravel/activitylog` and thats what I'm trying to delete, I access the Model with `Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity`, but it's not a local model. I'm trying to delete everything from the table that has been created from this package.

the delete function on my vue.js, the `baseUrl: 'logs'`

```
deleteAll(){
    this.$confirm('¿Desea borrar todos los registros del logs?', 'Advertencia', {
        confirmButtonText: 'Si',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        cancelButtonClass: 'el-button--info',
        confirmButtonClass: 'el-button--warning',
        type: 'warning'
    }).then(() => {
        this.$inertia.delete(this.baseUrl + '/delete')
            .then(
                () => {
                    this.$message({
                        type: 'success',
                        message: 'Eliminado correctamente.'
                    });
                    this.tableData = this.tableData.filter((item) => {
                        return item.id !== row.id
                    });
                },
                (res) => {
                    this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                }
            )
    })
},
```

The route

```
Route::delete('logs/delete', 'ActivityLogController@delete');
```

The delete on the controller

```
public function delete()
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    Activity::where('log_name', 'like', '%%')->delete();
    DB::commit();

    return back();
}
```

What happens is I click it a small window with a 404 opens up inside the main window and it shows the success message but nothing gets deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to delete everything, don't use a `where()` clause, just call `Model::delete()`

Comment: @TimLewis the same thing happens, it doesn't delete and the 404 windows still shows up. I added more info to the question.

Comment: Hmm, can't speak to the `vue.js` part of this question (don't know `vue` at all), but check your browser's network tab to see where the request is going, headers, etc., and check Laravel's logs (`storage/logs/`) for any errors, etc. My comment was more an observation on approach.

Comment: You probably posting to the wrong endpoint. 404 means not found. Probably Laravel can't resolve your url to an existing route. Try using network tab in your inspector.

Comment: @tprj29 this is what the network tab says 

Request URL: http://page.com/logs/delete
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 404 Not Found

Comment: @Nancy this tells you that laravel can't resolve page.com/logs/delete. Try adding a route. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but having `return back();` in an `AJAX` request is incorrect. You'd want to use something like `return response()->json([], 200);` Also, `php artisan route:list` will show you the routes/controller actions available.

Comment: Is your route an api route or a web route?

Comment: @tprj29 I did add a route

Comment: @TimLewis I'm using Inertia-vue

Comment: @chunterb a web route

Comment: Try this in your controller please. If it errors, check your storage log and let me know.
```
DB::beginTransaction();
Activity::truncate();
DB::commit();

return response()->json(['message' => 'Success'], 200);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```php
public function delete()
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        Activity::truncate();
        DB::commit();
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        Log::error("[ActivityDelete] An error occurred: " . $ex->getMessage());
        DB::rollback();
        return response()->json($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getStatusCode());
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Success'], 200);
}
```

I believe the 404 is from using `back()`, which is not a valid response for axios. And on top of that it is not deleting anyways, so there may be a problem with the way you are trying to delete as well.

If this fails - check your storage logs and report here please.

Comment: Good thoughts, just be careful with `truncate`; there are cases where you'd want to use it, but it doesn't respect some things like `softDeletes()`. I doubt that's an issue here, but just something to be aware of.

Comment: I'm using Inerita-vue and am using `return back()` everywhere in my project. I just replaced your return with return back and it worked perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your query. For example:

```
Activity::where('id', '>', 0)->delete();
```

Comment: This is irrelevant. The approach to deleting the records is not the issue here.